# N:N Relationship with Business Unit entity CRM Online 2016

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

Is it possible to create a N:N relationship between account and Business Unit in Crm Online 2016?
If not, is there any Microsoft post that mention it?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create native N:N relationships for Business Unit. Instead you can create a custom intersect entity with one lookup to Business Unit and one lookup to Account.

You do not write what you are trying to achieve, but be aware that Accounts are already natively connected to Business Units though the owning user or team.